# Leaflet maps /mobile phone

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is it possible to make `leaflet.js` map responsive on a mobile phone like google maps? Because when I try to go up or down on a mobile phone I can't.

The only option in my mind is to make two buttons up and down and save this problem.

This is the link of the page:
https://scopertemolise.000webhostapp.com/frosolone.html

Comment: No problem with your link

Comment: As illustrated by above comment, it sounds like people may not understand what you are referring to. Adding a screenshot / sketch of what you want to achieve would surely help.

Comment: I think that what Prutenay is confusing what "responsive" means, and what they really want is https://github.com/elmarquis/Leaflet.GestureHandling/

Comment: IvanSanchez thank's a lot.